# regex to find match in patterned data range?

Tags: javascript, filter

I have a table with 3 columns (contact person, sector, phone#) each sector cell would contain a lot of data numbers in range like these: (exact format without quote)

"1003, 1005-29/36/38/49, 4587-99, 3301/21, 50123, 9900-04/10-14/20/30/41-44"

Is there a way to add a filter (textbox) to the webpage for a quick look-up?

Example, if I type "9912" --> it will find the string: "9900-04/10-14/20/30/41-44" and highlight it.

note: I have no control over the table  (there is no id/class for that column or entire table), searching the entire webpage will be ok, there is no duplicate info elsewhere.

Can someone point me to a good direction? jQuery?

Comment: "Example, if I type "9912" --> it will find the string: "9900-04/10-14/ 20/30/41-44" and highlight it."  I still do not understand how you are trying to find the data , can you be more specific and let me know on what basis are you trying to search.

Comment: @D.Bugger sorry there shouldnt be a space before 20 (i corrected it) "9900-04/10-14/20/30/41-44" means: 9900,9901,9902,9903,9904,9910,9911,9912,9913,9914,9920,9930,9941,9942,9943 and 9944. he tricky thing is all my data is written in this kind of shorten format (since they are many). An user however, will always search an unique sector number (no regex in the user's input)

Comment: I think if you want to form a regex , you could look at this online tool , its pretty comprehensive and should work.http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/                   Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery will help you with the interaction for the textbox, but for processing the strings and extracting the data (i.e. which integers they match) you will need some heavy processing (using regular expressions, String.indexOf() and some loops). It's probably best to do all this processing on page load and cache the results somewhere, but depending on how many strings there are to process, this could lock up the user interface for a while, but assuming this isn't a problem then code a bit like this would do the job of highlighting the correct results

```
var dataCache = {};

$(selector to collect all your strings).each(function() {
    var string = $(this).html();
    var matches = yourParserWhichreturnsAnArrayOfIntegers(string);
    for(var i = 0, il = matches.length;i<il;i++) {
        if(dataCache[matches[i]]) {
            dataCache[matches[i]].push(this);    
        } else {
            dataCache[matches[i]] = [this];
        }
    }
});

$(yourtextbox).change(function() {
    $(selector to collect all your strings).removeClass("highlighted");
    var matches = dataCache[$(this).val()];
    if (matches) {
        for(var i=0,il=matches.length;i<il;i++){
            $(matches[i]).addClass("highlighted");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, so now I just need to find a way to parse all my shorten data into unique data and store them in a array of int. Wow this can be complicated for me haha~

Comment: it will be. My advice would be to start by getting rid of the "/" syntax if you can; if you restrict yourself to whole numbers and ranges indicated with '-' it'll be a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

If the table appears in the same location within the DOM everytime then you can still get at the data. If this is the case I think you will have to search in the expanded numbers. A regular expression for searching the compressed number format will probably be very complicated. Don't forget to keep a reference to the original data on the page so you can highlight it if a match is found.

Comment: What does it mean to have the table in same location as the DOM? Sorry I'm not very familiar with this. So if no regex, what method should I use? Thanks

Comment: The DOM is the Document Object Model and is what javascript uses to access elements on a web page. If your data table is, for example, always the 3rd table in the page then it will be accessible as document.getElementsByTagName('table')[2]. However if the position of the table changes then you will need another way of getting at it.